# How can I perform the following transformation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
    id      fruits                      fastfoods
0   1110    banana|grapes|pine apple    noodles|manchurian
1   1123    apple|orange|pine apple     friedrice|manchurian
2   1245    apple|grapes                noodles|fried rice
3   1710    banana|orange|pine apple    noodles|manchurian
4   1109    banana|apple|pine apple     manchurian
```

And I want to convert this dataframe as follows:

```
    id      banana  grapes  pineApple   apple   orange  noodles manchurian  friedRice
0   1110    yes     yes     yes         no      no      yes     yes         no
1   1123    no      no      yes         no      no      no      yes         yes
2   1245    no      yes     no          yes     no      yes     no          yes
3   1710    yes     no      yes         no      yes     yes     yes         no
4   1109    yes     no      yes         yes     no      no      yes         no
```

I tried a few things but nothing worked. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to replicate the dataframe from the question exactly, you can use the two lines of code below to format `pineApple` and `friedRice`. Then use the solution provided by @jezrael.      
`df['fastfoods'] = df['fastfoods'].str.replace(' ', '').str.replace('friedrice', 'friedRice')`  and 
`df['fruits'] = df['fruits'].str.replace('pine apple', 'pineApple')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index('id')
         .stack()
         .str.get_dummies()
         .max(level=0)
         .replace({0:'no', 1:'yes'})
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
     id apple banana fried rice friedrice grapes manchurian noodles orange  \
0  1110    no    yes         no        no    yes        yes     yes     no   
1  1123   yes     no         no       yes     no        yes      no    yes   
2  1245   yes     no        yes        no    yes         no     yes     no   
3  1710    no    yes         no        no     no        yes     yes    yes   
4  1109   yes    yes         no        no     no        yes      no     no   

  pine apple  
0        yes  
1        yes  
2         no  
3        yes  
4        yes
```

If order is important:

```
order = df.melt('id')['value'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().unique()
print (order)
['banana' 'grapes' 'pine apple' 'apple' 'orange' 'noodles' 'manchurian'
 'friedrice' 'fried rice']

df1 = (df.set_index('id')
         .stack()
         .str.get_dummies()
         .max(level=0)
         .replace({0:'no', 1:'yes'})
         .reindex(order, axis=1)
         .reset_index()
         )
print (df1)
     id banana grapes pine apple apple orange noodles manchurian friedrice  \
0  1110    yes    yes        yes    no     no     yes        yes        no   
1  1123     no     no        yes   yes    yes      no        yes       yes   
2  1245     no    yes         no   yes     no     yes         no        no   
3  1710    yes     no        yes    no    yes     yes        yes        no   
4  1109    yes     no        yes   yes     no      no        yes        no   

  fried rice  
0         no  
1         no  
2        yes  
3         no  
4         no
```

Comment: Got a warning 'FutureWarning: Using the level keyword in DataFrame and Series aggregations is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.' But fixed it by replacing .max(level=0) by .groupby(level=0).max()

Answer (score 2):

We can create the One-Hot Encoded values with [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) (the default separator is `'|'`), then use a comprehension over the desired columns to get all the values and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them together, and [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the `1/0` encoding with `yes/no`:

```
pd.concat(
    [df[col].str.get_dummies() for col in ['fruits', 'fastfoods']],
    axis=1
).replace({1: 'yes', 0: 'no'})
```

```
  apple banana grapes orange pine apple fried rice friedrice manchurian noodles
0    no    yes    yes     no        yes         no        no        yes     yes
1   yes     no     no    yes        yes         no       yes        yes      no
2   yes     no    yes     no         no        yes        no         no     yes
3    no    yes     no    yes        yes         no        no        yes     yes
4   yes    yes     no     no        yes         no        no        yes      no
```

We can then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to the ID column or any subset columns desired to get the final DataFrame:

```
new_df = df[['id']].join(
    pd.concat(
        [df[col].str.get_dummies() for col in ['fruits', 'fastfoods']],
        axis=1
    ).replace({1: 'yes', 0: 'no'})
)
```

`new_df`:

```
     id apple banana grapes orange pine apple fried rice friedrice manchurian noodles
0  1110    no    yes    yes     no        yes         no        no        yes     yes
1  1123   yes     no     no    yes        yes         no       yes        yes      no
2  1245   yes     no    yes     no         no        yes        no         no     yes
3  1710    no    yes     no    yes        yes         no        no        yes     yes
4  1109   yes    yes     no     no        yes         no        no        yes      no
```